# How to distribute component with different cell heights?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am trying to create an UI with components arranged in the order as shown in the picture?

I am building a Material UI Dialog in React application with the following design proposal.

I am trying to flex box. I tried using the concepts as in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax#the_flex-grow_property

but I am not able to achieve the result. Can the components be arranged as in the picture otherwise I will have to ask my client to reconsider the design decision which I am not sure will be possible but before I want to confirm the design possibility.

If it is possible to achieve, can anyone please give me a lead?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution for the template you showed but using the grid template instead of flex.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container{
  --gap: .20rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, auto) repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: var(--gap);
  padding: var(--gap);
  height: 100vh;
}

.container > *{
  border: solid 1px darkgray;
  display: block;
  background: lightgray;
}

.side{
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.header, .footer{
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.box{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Demo content */

.side::before,
.header::before,
.footer::before
{
  color: #444;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #777;
  display: block;
}

.side::before{
  content: 'sidebar';
}

.header::before{
  content: 'header';
}

.footer::before{
  content: 'footer';
}

.container > .box:nth-child(3)::before{
  height: 70%;
  /*content: attr(data-height);*/ /*I wished it worked but it didn't*/ 
}

.container > .box:nth-child(4)::before{
  height: 40%;
}

.container > .box:nth-child(5)::before{
  height: 90%;
}

.box::before{
  color: #ccc;
  background: red;
  border: solid 1px darkred;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  text-align: center;
  padding: .2em 1em;
  font-size: .8rem;
  content: 'height: ' attr(data-height);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="box" data-height="70%"></div>
  <div class="box" data-height="40%"></div>
  <div class="box" data-height="90%"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible with Flexbox. Here is an example:

```css
.block {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 8px;
}

.first-column {
  width: 100px;
}

.second-column {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
}

.second-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
}

.second-row>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.third-row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block container">
  <div class="block first-column">
    row 1
  </div>
  <div class="second-column">
    <div class="block">
      row 1
    </div>
    <div class="second-row">
      <div class="block">
        row 2
        <br /> row 2
        <br /> row 2
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        row 2
        <br /> row 2
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        row 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block third-row">
      row 3
      <br />
      <br />
      <br /> row 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```